# Background color not changing on hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to change element's background-color using random colors from an array. There is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

var randomColors = ['#00eeff','#fcff00','#9600ff'];
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColors.length);

$("div.anyclass").hover(
        function() {
 $(this).css({'background-color' : 'randomColors[rndNum]'}) 
 }, 
        function() {
 $(this).css({'background-color' : '#fff'});
        });
});
```

So, it doesn't work, where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove quotes from `'randomColors[rndNum]'` otherwise it becomes a mere string:

```
$(this).css({'background-color': randomColors[rndNum]})
```

OR

```
$(this).css({backgroundColor: randomColors[rndNum]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the quotes, like this:

```
$("div.anyclass").hover(function() {
   $(this).css({'background-color' : randomColors[rndNum]}) 
}, function() {
   $(this).css({'background-color' : '#fff'});
});
```

Currently it's trying to set the string as *exactly* `'randomColors[rndNum]'`, not the *value* of that entry in the array, e.g. `'#00eeff'`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$(this).css({'background-color' : 'randomColors[rndNum]'})
```

to this:

```
$(this).css({'background-color' : randomColors[rndNum]})
```

The variable won't be expanded if it's within a string.